# 252004: Failed processing pyformat-parameters; 255001: Binding data in type (timestamp) is not supported

Tags: python, dataframe, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to insert data into Snowflake from a pandas DataFrame but I am getting the error

*"252004: Failed processing pyformat-parameters; 255001: Binding data in type (timestamp) is not supported."*

Below is the code:

```
## REPLACING NaNs with Nones to fit Snowflake requirements
NULLING_MERGED_TABLES = [df.where(pd.notnull(df), None) for df in merged_dfs]

#Adding on the lead_ts again
for df in NULLING_MERGED_TABLES:
   df['LOAD_TS'] = pd.to_datetime('today').strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
   df['LOAD_TS'] = df['LOAD_TS'].astype(str)
   print(df.dtypes)

chunk_size = 10000

for dataframe, table in zip(NULLING_MERGED_TABLES, snowflake_tables):
    #delete the contents of the table so that the insert is new
    cs.execute(f"TRUNCATE TABLE {table}")
    column_headers = ', '.join(dataframe.columns)
    #print(dataframe['LOAD_TS'].dtypes)
    for i in range(0, len(dataframe), chunk_size):
        values = dataframe[i:i+chunk_size].values.tolist()
        cs.executemany(f"INSERT INTO {table} ({column_headers}) VALUES ({', '.join(['%s'] * len(dataframe.columns))})", values)

cs.close()
conn.close()
```

Even though you can see that I have converted the type of the load_ts column to a string. When I do df.dtypes I can see that there are no timestamp columns. How can I resolve this?